Ошибка '''incompatiblebrokerversion: kafka broker does not support the 'createtopicsrequest_v0' kafka protocol.'''
Разрабатываю простенький сервис email-рассылок на FastAPI. Понял (да и подсказали здесь же), что желательно использовать Kafka для обработки большой нагрузки. Поднял kafka через docker:

версия kafka - 3.1.0 ('docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.1.0'),
версия zookeper - 3.8.0 ('docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8.0').
Установил aiokafka версии 0.11.0 (первая на Pypi), при попытке создать тему, как я понял, выдает ошибку:

aiokafka.errors.incompatiblebrokerversion:     
    incompatiblebrokerversion: 
         kafka broker does not support the 'createtopicsrequest_v0' kafka protocol

Адекватного решения нигде не нашел, может тут кто подскажет.

Пишут, что такое может быть если KafkaAdminClient передаёт api_version. Как это лечить в вашем случае не знаю https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/pull/1953

Может, есть просто другие комбинации зависимостей и библиотек?

Тут только пробовать. Может в кафке посвежее это вылечили.
